# Equivalent conditions for a finite module over a Noetherian domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization, flatness

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian domain $R$. Further, let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Then by NAK all the minimal generating sets of the $R_\mathfrak p$-module $M_\mathfrak p$ have the same cardinality, which equals the dimension of the $R_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$-vector space $M_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p M_\mathfrak p$, where $\mathfrak pR_\mathfrak p$ is the maximal ideal in the local ring $R_\mathfrak p$.

> How does one show that $M$ is flat iff the cardinality of minimal
>   generating sets of $M_\mathfrak p$ is independent of $\mathfrak p$?

There is a proof of this (or something similar) in P. Clark's lecture notes (in fact, it is left as an exersise), but it uses a few theorems on projective modules. I'm wondering whether there is a way to establish this without appealing to projective modules?

(Note $M$ is flat iff $M_\mathfrak p$ is flat for all primes $\mathfrak p$ in $R$ iff $M_\mathfrak p$ is free for all primes $\mathfrak p$ in $R$ iff there are $r_1,\dots,r_n\in R$ such that $R=(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ and $M_{r_i}$ are all free over $R_{r_i}$.)

Comment: For a finitely presented module (in particular for a finitely generated module over a noetherian ring), flat and projective are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **forward direction** is a formal consequence of one of the equivalent definitions:

The characterization

> $M_\mathfrak p$ is free for all primes $\mathfrak p$ in $R$

shows that the rank of $M$ at all primes in $V(\mathfrak p)$ is the same as the rank at $\mathfrak p$. Since $R$ is a domain, we can pick $\mathfrak p=0$ and are done.

---

The **backward direction** can be shown like this:

Let $n$ be the dimension of $M_{(0)}$ over the fraction field. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal. By assumption, we know that $M_{\mathfrak p}$ can be generated by $n$ elements. A standard argument in localization shows that $M_{(0)}$ can be generated by the same $n$ elements. Since it is a vector space of dimension $n$, the elements form a basis, hence they are necessarily $R_{(0)}$-linear independent. In particular they are $R_{\mathfrak p}$-linear independent, hence they form a basis of $M_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: I don't see how $M_\mathfrak{p}$ being free translates into the condition being closed, but doesn't the fact that $M_{(0)}$ is a further localization of $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ just immediately imply $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free of rank $n$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$ (given that $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free)?

Comment: Yeah, thats precisely my argument. I just formulated it more locally, so that this part of the argument does not require $R$ to be a domain: If the rank of $M$ at $\mathfrak p$ is $n$, then the rank is $n$ in all of $V(\mathfrak p)$ by your argument. (You just picked the special case $\mathfrak p=0$ here)

Comment: Right, but that only gives that the condition is specialization-closed, not that it is closed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but thats certainly enough in our situation. One should phrase the forward direction in an easier way.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in proving both the implication you use a theorem like the one posted here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057528/claims-about-generators-of-a-localized-module - and refer to it as "a standard argument in localization"?